# Google map LocalContextMapView : no refresh when panning the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

when using new beta feature LocalContextMapView  from Google map, as described in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/local-context

How does one refresh the localContext when the map is panned/zoomed ?

Answer (score 0):

`LocalContextMapView` place search is strictly bound by the map viewport by default. You can use the `locationRestriction` parameter to set a bounds to be much larger than the map's initial viewport.

You can find the sample implementation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/local-context/samples/location-restriction

And, since Local Context Search is still in beta, I highly suggest that you file a feature request for having a function to set `locationRestriction` programatically/dynamically.

For example, having a `localContextMapView.setLocationRestriction()` property would be a great addition to the Local Context Library. You can use [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) to file a feature request.

Comment: The sample implementation is a good example : if you pan or unzoom the map, how do you arrange to have the Local Context updated ?  The sample implementation does not do it either.

Comment: Yes, like I said there is no feature yet to have Local Context be updated. Since Local Context is still in beta it may lack some features. I suggest that you file a feature request for the feature that you would like to see on the API. You can use  [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) to do that.